# Happens before guarantee in Volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through the **Java Concurrency in Practice** I came across the below statement related to the `Happens before guarantee` that `Volatile` provides

> Happens before relation when two threads synchronize using a common
> lock. All the actions within thread A are ordered by the program order
> rule, as are the actions within thread B. Because A releases lock M
> and B subsequently acquires M, all the actions in A before releasing
> the lock are therefore ordered before the actions in B after acquiring
> the lock. When two threads synchronize on different locks, we can't
> say anything about the ordering of actions between them there is no
> happens before relation between the actions in the two threads.

Can someone please elaborate a bit more on what exactly does this mean?

Comment: This quote from JCIP does not relate to `volatile`. Please clarify what you mean with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please elaborate a bit more on what exactly does this mean?

The quoted text is about the semantics of primitive locks.

Basically it says that if thread A writes to a shared variable V while holding a lock M, and then releases the lock, and then thread B acquires lock M and reads the shared variable V, then it will not see the value of V before the either before it was written by A.

It won't necessarily see the value written by A though because it is possible that another C thread wrote to V:

- If C wrote to V while holding the lock M, then B will see A's value if C's write was at a point in time before A's write.
- If C wrote to V without holding the lock, then it is unspecified what value B's read will see.

The semantics of `volatile` are a bit simpler.  If `A` writes a value to `volatile` V, and then if `B` reads `V` after `A`s write then it won't see the value of `V` before `A`'s write.  (It will either see what `A` wrote, or something written by some other thread at or after the time of `A`'s write.)

Answer (score 1):

In case you asking about `volatile` modificator.

Since Java 6 (I think) Happens Before behavior was changed for `volatile` variable.

Writting to `volatile` variable is **happens before reading** `volatile` variable. It means that e.g. you have `volatile int foo`, then if any thread writes to this variable, this changes will be definitely visible for another read. Another words, if you write smth. to `volatile` variable, it will be immideately synchronised with main memory (and not leaving in local thread cache only).

Comment: Volatile has no impact on writing a change to main memory. Changes can be in cache indefinitely; the primary thing is that the caches need to be coherent which normally is taken care of by the hardware.